# Error #valor! cuando ingreso una formula en funciones diferentes

Tags: excel, vba

Hola Pros de los Pros

Tengo una duda, actualmente estoy insertando unas formulas por medio de macros de las cuales tengo dos funciones una calcula el si el valor es nulo y la otra verifica el formato de un rango, estas formulas son ingresadas por medio de un botón. Tengo un problema que cuando ingreso la formula del si el valor es nulo

```
Range("M155").FormulaLocal = "=IF(VerificarFormatoNumerico('CM1'!O66:P66);1;0)"
```

Aparece el resultado normal, pero se me daña la otra formula que ingrese previamente ( no están relacionadas)

```
Range("M143").FormulaLocal = "=IF(VerificarFormatoNumerico('Hoja1'!B2:B31917);1;0)"
```

y el resultado es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto me toca ir a la celda, seleccionarla y darle enter para que me aparezca el resultado. Cuál es una posible solución para evitar este inconveniente desde la macro o porque se produce.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Y qué error te da en las casillas? (Qué mensaje sale en el signo de admiración?)

Comment: "Error in value" pero lo que te digo, al momento de yo hacer doble click en la casilla y darle enter la celda ya se arregla y aparece el valor pero es algo que quiero evitar porque son muchos registros

Comment: Por qué no utilizas las funciones IsNull e IsNumeric de vba? Así te olvidas de insertar fórmulas.

Comment: *al momento de yo hacer doble click en la casilla y darle enter la celda ya se arregla* Mmmm, ¿tienes el modo de cálculo automático o está en manual?

Comment: Por fin pude encontrar la respuesta y esta en este [enlace](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/on-off-calculations/)resulta que así como comento @Esei primero se debe pasar al inicio de la macro el calculo a manual porque al parecer excel una vez empieza el proceso empieza a hacer los cálculos y después ya asume que todo esta bien O es mi análisis. Pero como lo dije la respuesta esta en el link